# How to recursively create dictionary from identifiers?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a correspondence of "parent" and "child" ID numbers that I am trying to create a nested dictionary from.
I have:

```
child_dict = {11: [12, 13], 12:[], 13:[14], 14:[], 15:[]}
```

and I am trying to get to

```
output = {11: [12, {13:14}], 15:[]}
```

recursively. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: "best" is opinion-based. Just do it any way that works. If you want commentary on your design, post it to [codereview.se].

Comment: nothing that's worked lol. I'm trying to figure out a way with a loop but I'm just stuck

Comment: *" I am trying "*: please show your try.

Comment: @Barmar: Sounds like you missed the [memo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/message/91592#91592) saying Stack Overflow *is* a code-writing service.

Comment: @martineau I'm always the last to know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your output consistent, I believe `{13:14}` should be `{13:[14]}`.

Here is a recursive function to create the structure:

```
def create_tree(d):
    res = {}
    exclude = set() # The keys which are not roots 

    def dfs(key):
        if key not in res:
            exclude.update(d[key])
            res[key] = [
                child if tree == [] else { child: tree }
                for child, tree in map(dfs, d[key])
            ]
        return key, res[key]

    for key in d:
        dfs(key)
    # Only retain the root(s) at the toplevel:
    for key in exclude:
        res.pop(key)
    return res

    
child_dict = {11: [12, 13], 12:[], 13:[14], 14:[], 15:[]}
res = create_tree(child_dict)
print(res)
```